# How to handle a slow Telegram API call?

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement a fail check routine for a Telegram API call in case the API takes more than a second to run. If this occurs, the rest of the code needs to keep its normal execution flow and run down to the `return(res)` function. I have coded this way but I am not noticing that `return(res)` runs when the `withTimeout` portion takes more than a second

```
library(telegram)
library(R.utils)

bot <- TGBot$new(token = "111111:ssssssssssssssssss")
bot$set_default_chat_id("-811111111")
ValTiempo=1
sede1="TEST"
IdTiempo=2
      
print(paste('Start API Telegram', Sys.time()))
withTimeout(
      {
    
    bot$sendMessage( 
      paste0(
        "<u><b>MiCirugia</b></u>\n"
        ,ValTiempo, "\n"
        ,"Paciente sin cirugia programada\n"
        ,paste("Sede ", sede1,"\n")
        ,paste("IdTiempo",IdTiempo,"\n")
        )
      ,parse_mode= 'HTML' )
  }
  , timeout = 1.00
  , onTimeout = "silent")

#API response
print(paste('Respuesta API y fin de rutina ', Sys.time()))
return(res)
```